# Remove items from cart after 30 minutes - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, cart

I would like to remove items from cart for both logged in and guest shoppers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to build a custom module which has cronjob.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/config-guide/cron/custom-cron-tut.html

On the cronjob class `Magento\SampleMinimal\Cron\Test` you have to remove the quote item collection which is created 30min before.

### Remove by QuoteITem

```
<?php


namespace Magento\SampleMinimal\Cron;

class Test {

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Quote\Model\ResourceModel\Quote\Item\CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $itemCollectionFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository
     */
    protected $quoteRepository;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Quote\Model\ResourceModel\Quote\CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $quoteCollectionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Quote\Model\ResourceModel\Quote\CollectionFactory $quoteCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\ResourceModel\Quote\Item\CollectionFactory $itemCollectionFactory,  
        \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository $quoteRepository 
    ) {

        $this->quoteCollectionFactory = $quoteCollectionFactory;
        $this->quoteRepository = $quoteRepository;
        $this->itemCollectionFactory = $itemCollectionFactory;
    }
    public function getItemData()
    {   

                $fromTime = new \DateTime('now', new \DateTimezone('UTC'));
                $toTime = clone $fromTime;
                $fromTime->sub(\DateInterval::createFromDateString('30 minutes'));
                echo  $fromDate = $fromTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                echo $toDate = $toTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');


                $itemColelction =$this->itemCollectionFactory->create()
                      ->addFieldToSelect('created_at')
                       ->addFieldToSelect('item_id')
                       ->addFieldToSelect('quote_id')
                       ->addFieldToFilter('created_at', ['lteq' => $fromDate]);     

                if($quoteCollection->getSize() >0){
                    foreach ($itemColelction as $item)
                    {
                        $quote = $this->quoteRepository->get($item->getQuoteId());
                        $quote->deleteItem($item);

                    }
                }


    }
}
```

### Want to remove Quote then use

```
<?php


namespace Magento\SampleMinimal\Cron;

class Test {

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository
     */
    protected $quoteRepository;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Quote\Model\ResourceModel\Quote\CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $quoteCollectionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Quote\Model\ResourceModel\Quote\CollectionFactory $quoteCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository $quoteRepository 
    ) {

        $this->quoteCollectionFactory = $quoteCollectionFactory;
        $this->quoteRepository = $quoteRepository;
    }
    public function getItemData()
    {   


                $fromTime = new \DateTime('now', new \DateTimezone('UTC'));
                $toTime = clone $fromTime;
                $fromTime->sub(\DateInterval::createFromDateString('30 minutes'));
                echo  $fromDate = $fromTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                echo $toDate = $toTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                $quoteCollection = $this->quoteCollectionFactory->create();
                /*
                $quoteCollection
                    ->addFieldToFilter('created_at', ['lteq' => $toDate])
                    ->addFieldToFilter('created_at', ['gteq' => $fromDate]);
                 * 
                 */
                $quoteCollection
                    ->addFieldToFilter('created_at', ['lteq' => $fromDate]);                
                //echo $quoteCollection->getSelect()->__toString();

                if($quoteCollection->getSize() >0){
                    foreach ($quoteCollection as $quote)
                    {
                        $quoteFullObject = $this->quoteRepository->get($quote->getId());
                        $quoteFullObject->delete();
                    }
                }


    }
}
```

Comment: i have need code to get all cart item

Comment: you need quote item or quote?